# Python Sorting with lambda

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have a question

```
A = [3,2,4,1]
N = len(A)
B = sorted(range(N), key = lambda i: A[i])
print(B)
output #[3, 1, 0, 2]

input #A = [7,2,4,1]
output #[3, 1, 2, 0]
```

I do not understand the output ?? Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: This is kind of numpy argsort. It's giving you the index of the sorted array. For the first array, the sorted list is [1, 2, 3, 4], so the arg list is [3, 1, 0, 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda: ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda) and [What is key=lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669252/what-is-key-lambda) and [What does this mean: key=lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310015/what-does-this-mean-key-lambda-x-x1)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about the specific example you have used

> A = [3, 2, 4, 1]
>
> N = len(A) .  # N = 4
>
> B = sorted(range(N), key = lambda i: A[i])   # sorted([0,1,2,3], key= lambda i:A[i])

Basically you are trying to sort [0,1,2,3] based on the values A[i] which are [3,2,4,1]

Now, `A[3] < A[1] < A[0] < A[2]`

And so you get the answer as `[3, 1, 0, 2]`

Answer (score 0):

In the `sorted` function the first element is the item you would like to sort. If you can you sort a generator that is converted to a list of size 4. The sorting function sorts according to the value given by the anonymous function.

In your case - `A = [3, 2, 4, 1]`
List to sort - `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Keys for each element `[3, 2, 4, 1]`. Basically you can imagine you sort `[(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1)]` according to the second element and then left with the first element and this results `[3, 1, 0, 2]` you get.